# CoreBluetooth: Can you connect to a peripheral device that is not advertising

Tags: ios, ios5, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

If the iOS application has already paired with a BLE peripheral that has gone out of advertising mode, can it connect using only the device-specific `UUID`, `retrievePeripherals`, and `connectPeripheral`?

If not, is there only one mode that the peripheral can advertise in, or are there varying levels of privacy/identification that can be set when advertising?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it cannot. To create a connection to any peripheral device, that device would have to advertise using connectable advertising. The device that wants to connect, will then have to reply to one of the advertisements with a connection request.

Comment: Would connectable advertising require the device display the same data as any other public device? I'm trying to see if paired devices can connect privately.

Comment: In subsequent connections, the device can use _connectable directed advertising_, which does not display any data, just addresses. For additional privacy, the device can enable the privacy feature. It will then use a different device address for every connection. The address is then either a _non-resolvable private address_, a random address that is refreshed and communicated to the central device in every connection as a "reconnection address", or it is a _resolvable private address_ which is consisting of a random part and a hash using an Identity Resolving Key distributed during bonding.

Comment: Excellent, that's what I wanted to find out. Thanks!

Comment: How do other accessory manufacturers get around this?  I don't want my user to have to put the peripheral into advertising mode every time they turn on my app in order to connect.

Comment: As the accessory (BLE peripheral) have to advertise for a connection to be established, your would either need to have the peripheral advertising all the time when it is not in a connection, or the user must put it in advertising mode. Advertising can be done with a very low frequency, using a period of up to 10.24 seconds to save power. Alternatively you could manually start and stop advertising on a timer to get even lower frequency and power consumption, at the cost of added experienced latency for the app user.